# Como puedo seleccionar registros con un solo nombre en sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Apenas estoy empezando a aprender SQL y quiero hacer lo siguiente: Teniendo una tabla con nombres tipo

```
Id Nombre
1  Juan Perez
2  Pepe
3  Maria Suarez
```

La idea es seleccionar solo aquellos que tengan un solo nombre, en este caso sería Pepe.

He intentado hacer esto con regexp_like:

```
select * from Tabla where regexp_like(nombre,'[:blank:]$');
```

Ahí según tengo entendido, debería de dar los nombres que acaban con espacio en blanco, pero no he sabido la verdad como lograr que me muestre entonces solo los de 1 único nombre, simplemente me muestra todos los registros, la idea es lograr esto usando la función regexp_like y/o trim.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Exceptuando nombres compuestos como "Juan José" y considerando que no hay espacios ni al principio ni al final de `Nombre`, puedes probar la inexistencia de espacio en la cadena con [`INSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions058.htm#sthref1330).

Comment: @Sal Gracias por la respuesta pero disculpe no especifiqué antes, debo lograr esto y me puedo ayudar de regexp_like y/o trim pero no más. Hay alguna forma? Que pena y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa la expresión regular `^(\w+)$` la cual simplemente matchea cualquier nombre formado por caracteres de la A a la Z sin espacios. La consulta quedaría:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE regexp_like(nombre,'^(\w+)$');
```

De manera alternativa, en caso de que permitas nombres con caracteres especiales, podrías usar `^(\S+)$`, que básicamente matchea todo lo que no tenga espacios:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE regexp_like(nombre,'^(\S+)$');
```

Recuerda que en caso de que tu campo contenga espacios de más al inicio  o al final de la cadena, puedes aplicar `trim` antes del regex:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE regexp_like(trim(nombre),'^(\S+)$');
```